# Have Jonathan Pie's "allegations" been supported by the Privileges Committee report? "he lied, and did it again by denying that he’d previously lied"

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament, boris-johnson, member-of-parliament

The Evening Standard's June 20, 2023 [MPs overwhelmingly back report finding Boris Johnson deliberately misled Parliament over Partygate](https://www.standard.co.uk/news/politics/boris-johnson-partygate-vote-mps-commons-covid-b1088913.html) begins:

> MPs voted by 354 to seven to accept a report finding Boris Johnson deliberately misled the House of Commons over Partygate.

16 months ago I asked [Are there restrictions in the UK against calling politicians liars?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/70633/16047) in which I link to the fictitious character [Johnathan Pie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Pie)'s political satire in the very real New York Times video [Jonathan Pie: 'Boris Johnson Is a Liar' | NYT Opinion](https://youtu.be/QS7kUqKeg_0)

After 03:28 in the **February 5, 2022** video:

> PIE: Boris denied any knowledge of any parties until it became clear he was at some of them.
>
> JOHNSON: “Mr. Speaker, I want to apologize.”
>
> PIE: I.e., he lied. To the country and to Parliament. **And he did it again this week** when he lied to Parliament by denying that he’d previously lied to Parliament.
>
> And that’s Boris all over.

As far as "he lied" goes, it seems the answer is yes. **But for "He did it again this week"** is Pie's assertion also supported by the recently approved Privileges Committee report?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The report of the privileges committee did not directly find Johnson's statements referred to in the video in the question misleading. The statements denying any misleading of the house referred to in the video in the questions took place on January 31st, and are immortalised in [Hansard](https://hansard.parliament.uk/commons/2022-01-31/debates/6B412B49-AB7D-4FE3-9F82-B9EAE93FB6AC/SueGrayReport).

Firstly, Johnson replied to Ian Blackford, then-leader of the SNP in Westminster, who has accused him of 'wilfully misleading the house':

> I am grateful to the right hon. Gentleman for withdrawing what he just said, because he was wrong, and I am afraid that he is wrong in his analysis.

Secondly, Labour MP Karl Turner accused Johnson of inadvertently misleading the House in his comments on December 8th 2021, denying that such a party had taken place. Again, Johnson denied this claim: "No. I stand by what I said".

Catherine West then asked the Prime Minister directly whether he had misled the House in a response to her on December 8th. Johnson replied that he stuck by what he said to her at that time.

[The report](https://committees.parliament.uk/publications/40412/documents/197199/default/) does not include Johnson's statements on this occasion in the list of incidences of him misleading the House. The occasions on which Johnson *was* found to have misled the House are enumerated in paragraphs 188 to 189 of the report.

However, as the report does find (in paragraph 201) that Johnson's statements on December 8th 2021 were *intentionally* misleading, rather than inadvertent, it seems clear logically that Johnson's subsequent statements denying this, in particular his response to Ian Blackford on January 31st, were also intentionally misleading - vindicating the accusations in the video in the question.